# Issue with rails s (with sass apparently)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I tried to run `rails s` but sudently I'm getting an error message:

```
/home/leiver/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass (LoadError)
        from /home/leiver/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
        from /home/leiver/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
        from 
.....
```

I know that there's something about sass about how it's going to disapear or something and I don't know if it's linked

Thanks if you can help :)

EDIT

here's my full Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.4.5'

gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails', '5.2.1'
gem 'redis'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.0.9'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'devise'
gem 'money-rails'
gem "pundit"

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end
```

Comment: Do you have any sass gem in your gemfile?

Comment: In my Gemfile I have `gem 'sassc-rails'`, I tried to run `gem instal sass` but it still won't appear in my Gemfile

Comment: You might try deleting your bootsnap cache in tmp/cache/bootsnap-compile-cache & posting your full Gemfile in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried `bundle` or `bundle install` before running the rails s.
Still not working try to replace that gem with this`gem 'sassc'` and bundle or just do `gem install sassc`

Comment: I tried `bundle`, also `gem install sassc` , the gem is successfully installed but I keep getting the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I couldn't resolve the problem, so **I deleted my local directory and re-cloned it from GitHub**.
I don't know if it's good practice but it resolved the problem for me, so if anyone else is having this issue and don't find a proper solution, try doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be exists in **gems**. The problem founded by OP (and described in his answer) appears in the application files. However same problem problem may be caused in **gems**. The same problem in **gems** with same reason has identical solution.

In details. The problem during installation or some else may corrupt some gem so it is visible as installed but actually has missed or corrupted files. Check before that hard drive has **enough free space**.

So solution is **fully reinstall bundle** gems:

```sh
bundle install --force
```

Comment: The `--force` option has apparently been deprecated and renamed `--redownload`. Still worked for me, but thought I should point out in case someone comes across this in the future when it's actually gone.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all of the files within the **tmp** folder.

And it worked!